# Can't figure out where empty space is coming from

Tags: html, css, space

My sample webpage has a weird amount of empty space that I just cannot figure out why it is there. the link to the page is here "http://www.albany.edu/~jc191638/html/finalproject.html" I figure it would be easier to look at the sourcecode there rather than paste it. The empty space I am talking about is in the "computer science textbook" section and throws off the alignment at the bottom.

The css for the page is here

```
body
{
    background-color:    #DCDDD8;
    margin:0;   
}
p
{
    clear:left;
}
hr
{
    width:98%;
}
img
{ width:100%;
height:100%;
float:center;
}
h1
{
text-align:center;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc,
               0 2px 0 #c9c9c9,
               0 3px 0 #bbb,
               0 4px 0 #b9b9b9,
               0 5px 0 #aaa,
               0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
               0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
               0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3),
               0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
               0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25),
               0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
               0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
border-style:solid;
border-color:    #D74B4B;
}
#wrapper {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1200px;
    float:center;
}
#upper
{
    float:center;   
}
#upperleft
{
//margin:2%;
    //border:1px solid;
//border-radius:2px;    
float:left;
    width: 600px;
    height:300px;
            //margin:0%;
//border:1px solid;
border-radius:2px;
}
#upperright
{
    //float:right;
    //margin:2%;
    //border:1px solid;
//border-radius:2px;
float:right;
    width: 600px;
    height:300px;

    //margin:0%;
    //border:1px solid;
border-radius:2px;
} 
div
{
    float:left;
}
#middle
{
    width:100%;
    float:center;

}
#header
{
    height:150px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#DCDDD8;

}
#sidebar
{
    float:left;
    height:984px;
    width:250px;
    background-color:    #475F77;
    border-style:solid;
border-color:    #D74B4B;
}
#iphone
{
height:230px;
width:230px;
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
padding-top:10px;
}
#bottomside
{
    background-color:    #475F77;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
#googleglass
{
    height:230px;
    width:230px;
}
#navbar
{
width:107%;
background-color: #DCDDD8;  
}
.navele
{
    width:10%;
    text-align:center;
        border-style:solid;
border-color:    #D74B4B;;
}
a:link, a:visited
{
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
color:   #475F77;
display:block;
padding-top:3px;
padding-bottom:5px; 
text-decoration:none;)
}
a:hover
{
color: #DCDDD8;
background-color:#475F77;   
}
#border
{
    height:800;
    width:150;
    border:10px;
    padding-left:50px;
}
#current
{
    float:center:
    height:984px;
    width:600px;
    background-color:    #475F77;
    padding-bottom:10px;
        text-align:center;
        border-style:solid;
    border-color:    #D74B4B;
}
#nintendo
{
    height:70%;
    width:70%;
    padding-left:10px;
}
#nintext
{
    float:right;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-top:100px;
}
#wrapper2
{
margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:125px;
    float:right;
}
#wrapper3
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:600px;
    float:center;
    background-color:    #475F77;
}
#textbook
{
    height:25%;
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    padding-left:15px;

}
#wrapper4
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:125px;
    float:center;
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-left:150px;
}
#iclicker
{
    height:30%;
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
#clicktext
{
    float:right;
}
#wrapper5
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:250px;
    float:center;
    padding-top:75px;
    padding-left:250px;
}
#bar
{
    width:100%;
    }
#pens
{
 height:40%;
 width:40%;
 float:left;
 padding-left:15px;
 }
#wrapper6
{
margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:150px;
    float:center;
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-left:300px;
}
#rightbar
{
float:right;
    height:984px;
    width:250px;
    background-color:    #475F77;
    text-align:center;
border-style:solid;
border-color:    #D74B4B;
}
#login
{
float:center;
padding-left:15px;
}
#bottom
{
    width:1197px;
    height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:    #475F77;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:    #D74B4B;
    padding-top:15px;
    margin-top:15px;
}
#items
{
    width:70%;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}
#cart
{
    width:30%;
    text-align:center;
    text-style:bold;
    float:right;
}
#fb
{
    height:5%;
    width:18%
}
```

Comment: Not sure which space is bothering you but it is sometimes common to perform a 'reset' in css like: body,html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

Comment: Please clean up this code by removing the spaces that aren't necessary. It will make it significantly more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `#nintext` (`<p id="nintext"></p>` is a child of `<div id="wrapper3"></div>`). It has a `padding-top` of `100px` which is causing your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have different problems:

- You use custom heights bigger than content's height
- You have paddings
- You have margins
- You have empty paragraphs, which have margin by default. Please fix this, it's unsemantic.

I can't be more specific because I can't know which spaces you want and which ones you don't want.

Then, my suggestion is: learn to debug.

For example, if you use Firefox, right-click the element which has margin, choose Inspect Element, and [Page Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector#HTML_pane) will open. Chrome and IE have similar tools.